# Get Ember Data model relationship type

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm using Ember 1.13.2 and Ember-data 1.13.4

I'm trying to find the out the type of relationship that a model has.  Take the following example model.

```
// my post model
export default DS.Model.extend({
  author: DS.belongsTo('author'),
  comments: DS.hasMany('comment')
});
```

How can I check in my code if `comments` is a hasMany or belongsTo relationship?

At the moment I have worked out two solutions that work, but they feel a bit messy to me and I'm sure there must be a better way.

one way that works is this

```
var relationship = post.get(relationshipName); // relationshipName = 'comments'

if ( relationship.constructor.toString().indexOf('Array') !== -1 ) {
    relationshipType = 'hasMany';
}
else if ( relationship.constructor.toString().indexOf('Object') !== -1 ) {
    relationshipType = 'belongsTo';
}
```

another way that works

```
var relationship = post.get(relationshipName); // relationshipName = 'comments'

if (relationship.get('@each')) {
    relationshipType = 'hasMany';
}
else {
    relationshipType = 'belongsTo';
}
```

they both work, but they both feel a bit clunky to me and I don't know how reliable they are.

So the question is, which is the more reliable method?.. or is there a better way?

Comment: When accessing the relationship with `post.get('comments')` you are given the values - not a special relationship object. Depending on your code I'd suggest moving the code to the post model itself, like: `post.doSomethingWithAllBelongsTo()` and add that method to your post model. There you can access all relationships of that model with `this.eachRelationship`, where you can access the kind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check the `fields` for that.

```
import Post from '../models/post'

Ember.get(Post, 'fields').get('comments'); // hasMany
```

Or if you have an instance of a model you can check off the constructor:

```
Ember.get(post.constructor, 'fields').get('comments'); // hasMany
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for [Model.eachRelationship](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#method_eachRelationship)
example:

```
model.eachRelationship(function(name, descriptor) {
  if (descriptor.kind === 'hasMany') {
      //do something here
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks you! Cool answer

Answer (score 0):

As hasMany returns instance of DS.ManyArray and belongsTo returns DS.Model you can check via instanceof:

```
var something = post.get(relationshipName); // relationshipName = 'comments'
var relationshipType = 'belongsTo';
if(something instanceof DS.ManyArray) {
  relationshipType = 'hasMany';
}
```

Going further you can use the following code to determine if the field is not a model at all (i.e. computed property):

```
var something = post.get(name);
var propertyType = 'unknown';
if(something instanceof DS.ManyArray) {
  propertyType = 'relationship:hasMany';
} else if(something instanceof DS.Model) {
  propertyType= 'relationship:belongsTo';
} else if(/*whatever you want*/) {
  propertyType = /*whatever you want*/;
} else {
  propertyType = 'unknown';
}
```

Another way, if you don't want to import DS for any reason is to check for 'relationship' property:

```
var something = post.get(relationshipName); // relationshipName = 'comments'
var relationshipType = relationship.hasOwnProperty('relationship') ? 'hasMany' : 'belongsTo';
```

This one is OK only if you're sure that "something" is relationship, because it would give you false-positive if "something" is just a model, computed property etc.

Comment: This doesn't work anymore with Ember Octane (>3.15). Any advice on how to use instanceof ManyArray with Octane? I think the tricky part is the import of ManyArray since `import DS from 'ember-data'` is no longer supported.